# Isabelle tactic profiling

Tags: isabelle

Are there any tools to profile tactics in Isabelle?

I basically have a tactic of the form

```
REPEAT ( tac1 ORELSE ... ORELSE tacN )
```

I want to figure out how long each of the tactics runs, to identify
hot-spots for optimization.

I may need to do this in a nested way, e.g.

```
tac1 = tac12 THEN simp_tac ...
```

and I want to know how much time is spent on the simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there is `timeit` in ML, which you can wrap around functions. Here's an Eisbach wrapper:

```
ML \<open>fun method_evaluate text ctxt facts =
  Method.NO_CONTEXT_TACTIC ctxt
    (Method.evaluate_runtime text ctxt facts)\<close>


method_setup timeit =
 \<open>Method.text_closure >> (fn m => fn ctxt => fn facts =>
   let
     fun timed_tac st seq = Seq.make (fn () => Option.map (apsnd (timed_tac st))
       (timeit (fn () => (Seq.pull seq))));
     fun tac st' =
       timed_tac st' (method_evaluate m ctxt facts st');
   in SIMPLE_METHOD tac [] end)
\<close>
```

(https://github.com/seL4/l4v/blob/0f38e20094/lib/Eisbach_Methods.thy#L76)

Since this selection of Eisbach wrappers has just come up in another question, I'll have a look at including most of it in the distribution.

Comment: Have now added this one to HOL-Eisbach.Eisbach